# onClick changes to user input display and new textView

Tags: android, arrays, onclick, android-edittext, textview

onClick I would like to have question2 replace question1--instead of both being visible at the same time-- and have the users input to the second question go into it's appropriate textView.  My error occurs when I try to loop the array:"questionNumber++".

```
package com.example.greg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class menu extends Activity {

Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userAnswereditText);

    final TextView [] myTexts = new TextView[2];
    myTexts[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varATextView);
    myTexts[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varBTextView);

    final int questionNumber = 0;
    mButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
       {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {                
                myTexts[questionNumber].setText(mEdit.getText().toString());
                mEdit.setText(null);
                questionNumber++;      
            }
        }); 
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Comment: you initialize the questionNumber with final it can't be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class menu extends Activity {

 Button   mButton;
 EditText mEdit;
 int questionNumber = 0;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userAnswereditText);

final TextView [] myTexts = new TextView[2];
myTexts[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varATextView);
myTexts[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varBTextView);


mButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener()
   {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            myTexts[questionNumber].setText(mEdit.getText().toString());
            mEdit.setText(null);
            myTexts[0].setvisibility(View.GONE); // use this to hide
            myTexts[1].setvisibility(View.VISIBLE); // use this to show
            questionNumber++;

        }
    });

    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
}
```

Just remove the word final with questionNumber, what i did is initialize it at class level so I can access it in onclick method without declaring it final. Hope it helps.

Comment: The variable textViews work just fine now but my question textViews do not change to the next question onClick.  I am not sure if the way to achieve the effect of a new question appearing onClick has to do with visbility and placing the question textViews directly on top of eachother?  I would very much appreciate an answer to this.

Comment: use .setvisibility(View.GONE); to hide and .setvisibility(View.VISIBLE); to show

Comment: did it helped? if there is any other problem feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring textview[] "final" ... therefore on index 0 your value will not change .. so remove it .. also remove "final" from int

```
public class menu extends Activity {


Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

@Override
protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userAnswereditText);

TextView [] myTexts = new TextView[2];
myTexts[0]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varATextView);
myTexts[1]=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.varBTextView);

int questionNumber = 0;
mButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener()
   {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {                
            myTexts[questionNumber].setText(mEdit.getText().toString());
            mEdit.setText(null);
            questionNumber++;      
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
}
}
```